# Where to find stored procedure msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to look at the code for stored procedure `msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail` in SQL Server. Could someone tell me where to look for the stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio 2008.

Answer (score 20):

Right there:

[image]

As the name already tells you - it's in the `msdb` database (which is under the `System Databases`), and the stored proc can be found under `Programmability > System Stored Procedures`

Answer (score 8):

```
USE msdb;
GO

sp_helptext 'dbo.sp_send_dbmail';
```

OR

```
USE msdb;
GO

SELECT definition 
    FROM sys.sql_modules 
    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.sp_send_dbmail');
```

Answer (score 5):

From the Object Explorer node for your instance expand...

```
Databases -> System Databases -> msdb -> Programmability -> 
              Stored Procedures -> System Stored Procedures
```

Or (having seen Joe's answer) one non UI method

```
use msdb;

SELECT object_definition(object_id('dbo.sp_send_dbmail')) 
AS [processing-instruction(x)] FOR XML PATH('')
```